# Could this function be parallelized using OpenCL?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I am trying to improve execution time by porting some CPU functions from a project on GPU, using OpenCL.

Using VS profiler I noticed that the most execution time is spent on InsertCandidate() function, I'm thinking about writing a kernel to execute this function on GPU. The most expensive operation of this function is a `for` instruction. But as it can be seen, each for cycle contains 3 `if` instructions, and this can lead to divergence, resulting in serialization, even if executed on GPU.

```
template <class Tp>
int InsertCandidate( std::list<Tp> &detected, const Tp &box, double &nProbThreshold, int nMaxCandidate, double nMinProb )
{
    if( box._prob < nMinProb && box._prob < nProbThreshold )
        return -1;
    // Only use detection score to select positives.
    if( nMaxCandidate == 0 )
    {
        if( box._prob > nMinProb )
            detected.push_back( box );
        return 0;
    }

    typename std::list<Tp>::iterator    iter;
    int nCandidate = 0;

    for( iter = detected.begin(); iter != detected.end(); iter++ )
    {
        if( nCandidate == nMaxCandidate-1 )
            nProbThreshold = iter->_prob;

        if( box._prob >= iter->_prob )
            break;
        if( nCandidate >= nMaxCandidate && box._prob <= nMinProb )
            break;
        nCandidate ++;

    }

    if( nCandidate < nMaxCandidate || box._prob > nMinProb )
        detected.insert( iter, box );
    return 0;
}
```

As a conclusion, can this program be converted to openCL?

Comment: It seems to me that you are using linear search for inserting objects in a list. Linear search is slow and you should consider whether the algorithm could be changed to avoid constantly modifying a list of objects. From the code that you provide, it is almost impossible to tell if employing OpenCL is a good idea.